# Get value from a dynamic button without submit

Tags: javascript

I'm new in this world. I love it but it's very difficult if you don't have enough experience/skills.

I have a dynamic php page that shows data from db inside a table. I have to open a popup from a dynamic button, positioned on the side of every row, is created based on certain requirements.
Inside the popup I have to show the line that corresponds to the clicked button.
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeTXF.png)

This is the code for the button:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn0" name="button" onclick="openPopup()" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
```

Example: the first row has 'id' = 1; by clicking the corresponding button of that row, I have to show in the popup the data that matches to the row with 'id' = 1.
For obvious reasons, It always shows the last row.

In the general table the data is displayed through the classic while loop 'while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($controllo))'.

I tried with form, but I can't upload the page, the popup window is just a <div> element.

The function openPopup() displays the div:

```
function openPopup() {
    document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";
}
```

Inside the div there is a form where I can submit a change of the specific row.
I know i can use Javascript, but then I need php to show datat and submit the changes to db. Maybe there's something I'm skipping over.

Sorry for my english and tell me if you need something else.
Thanks to anyone who can help me.

EDIT: On button click the popup shows the specific row that refer to the button clicked. If I click on the button on the first row, the popup displays the first row, if I cick the button on the second row, it displays the second row, etc.
[Popup if I click on the first button, first row.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dJio.png)

EDIT: I try to be more clear.
On main page I have this:

```
<table class="tabella">
<thead>
    <tr class="intestazione">
        <th>Tipo di controllo</th>
        <th>Descrizione controllo</th>
        <th>Tool necessari</th>
        <th>Frequenza</th>
        <th>OK</th>
        <th>KO</th>
        <th>Note</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($controllo)){
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php echo $row['nome']; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $row['testo']; ?>
        </td>
        
    ....
```

I just get data from database and display as table and form.

Here you can check checkboxes and write note, and in the end submit the changes. It is a maintenance checklist.
On specific condition, after submit and reload, You have to be able to add a second note.

The problem is that I have to display, inside the div popup, the right row with his data, and then submit the new changes..

Comment: Do you mean each button has its own id value, what do you want it that when the button is clicked, the row-specific value will submitted to the server?

Comment: `getElementById("myForm")` targets _one_ element on your page. (`id`s must be unique) `type="submit"` should be `type="button"` if you don't want to submit

Comment: What is in `myForm`? Is that the same data that is in the html table, or more data? Where is it populated? If it's populated as part of your `while()` loop and there's only one form, then of course it will only contain the data from the last row. Doesn't your `openPopup()` function need to retrieve the data, populate `myForm`, then display it, then submit any changes?

Comment: the whole scenario is not perfectly clear in details but I may suggest to use a regular button (`type="button"`)  and doing `onclick="openPopup(this)"` so that to the function called will be passed the element triggering the event that you can use later for the sake of knowing which row originated the process

Comment: Is this a JS problem, or a PHP problem?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to get its value without submitting you have to use "prevenDefault"

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

here's an exemple :

```
document.getElementById('buttonid').addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    return e.target.value;
})
```

I'd also advise you to take at look at stopPropagation which can be quite handy https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

If you want to manage when to submit or not you can also use a function which'll take the event as a parameter

```
const getValue = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    return e.target.value;
}

    document.getElementById('buttonid').addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
    if(somecondition){
        getValue(e);
    }
    // If you don't want to get the value don't use else, 
    // if the if isn't triggered then it'll submit
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the button value when the button is clicked without form submission, you can refer to the following code for detail:

```js
function openPopup(e) {
  e.preventDefault();  //prevent form submission.
  console.log(e.target.value)
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="btn0" name="button" onclick="openPopup(event)" value="qk">go</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be a frame work for your entire page. Now, that you use PHP on the back-end both the table and the `data` object in the JavaScript element are dynamically generated (just like you describe in your question). I create the `data` object to make it easier to copy the data to the dialog form when one of the edit buttons is clicked.

As long as a button has the `type="button"` it will not submit the form. I made an event listener for any click event on the form, so I need to test 8with the `switch()`) if the clicked element has the right name.

I took the freedom to introduce the [`<dialog>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog). Maybe you could find it useful. When the dialog is closed with the save button, the values of each input is copied to the hidden input elements in form01, and then form01 is submitted (and the entire page reloaded -- you could also use AJAX, but that complicates things, now that this is new to you).

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var data = [{
      id: 1234,
      desc: "Test 1234"
    }, {
      id: 1235,
      desc: "Test 1235"
    }];
    var dialog, form01, form02;
    
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
      dialog = document.getElementById('dialog01');
      form01 = document.forms.form01;
      form02 = document.forms.form02;
      
      form01.addEventListener('click', e => {
        switch(e.target.name){
          case 'edit':
            let itemid = parseInt(e.target.dataset.id);
            let item = data.find(item => item.id == itemid);
            form02.desc.value = item.desc;
            form02.id.value = item.id;
            dialog01.showModal();
            break;
        }
      });
      
      dialog.addEventListener("close", e => {
        if(e.target.returnValue == 'save'){
          form01.id.value = form02.id.value;
          form01.desc.value = form02.desc.value;
          form01.submit();
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form name="form01"  action="/save.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="id">
    <input type="hidden" name="desc">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>Test 1234</td>
        <td><button type="button" name="edit" data-id="1234">Edit</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1235</td>
        <td>Test 1235</td>
        <td><button type="button" name="edit" data-id="1235">Edit</button></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
  <dialog id="dialog01">
    <form method="dialog" name="form02">
      <input type="hidden" name="id">
      <label>Description:<input type="text" name="desc"></label>
      <button value="cancel">Cancel</button>
      <button value="save">Save</button>
    </form>
  </dialog>

</body>

</html>
```